# Почему вызов конструктора не задает значение числа?

Tags: java

Почему конструктор Twins в классе Twins (имя конструктора должно называться по имени класса) не задает число n и limit?

Вывод:

```
Дано число n: 0, limit = 0
```

Сам код:

```
package com.company;
class Twins{
    int n = 0,
    limit = 0;

// Конструктор (Метод) - для генерации числа n
public void Twins(){
    while (true){
        n = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        if(n > 2) { 
            limit = 2 * n;
            break;
        }
    }

}
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Twins twins = new Twins();
        System.out.println("Дано число n: " + twins.n + ", limit = " + twins.limit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не конструктор:

```
public void Twins(){
```

Это конструктор:

```
public /*void*/ Twins(){
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Если конструктор не возвращает значения, почему при создании конструктора не нужно использовать void?

Comment: @n199a Конструктор отличается от остальных методов тем, что называется так же как класс, и перед ним не указывается возвращаемый тип.

Comment: Конструктор "возвращает" экземпляр класса