# Значение по умолчанию при создании объекта String

Tags: java

**Имеется инициализация:**

```
String[] newStr = new String[3];
```

Размер объекта newStr типа String принимает значение 3, простым языком говоря, создается массив строк размером 3 с неизвестной ещё длиной.

**По умолчанию строки заполняются null-значениями, т.е. по факту:**

```
newStr[0] = 'null';
newStr[1] = 'null';
```

При попытке внести что-нибудь в newStr[0] (например), к тексту добавляется ещё и 'null'. Добавляем слово "Регистр" и на выходе получаем "nullРегистр".

Вот часть моего кода, попадающего под вопрос:

```
char array[];

/* ТУТ КОД СОРТИРУЕТ СИМВОЛЫ И ДОБАВЛЯЕТ ИЗ В МАССИВ array[]*/

//добавление символов из переменной ch типа char в объект newStr типа String
public void connect(int i, char ch[]){
    for(int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++) {
        newStr[i] += ch[j];
    }
}

//создание объекта
public void setNewSize(String str[]){
    newStr = new String[str.length];
}
```

**Вопрос:**

Как убрать null при инициализации или вообще, как избавиться от null?

Comment: покажи код своего *добавления* к тексту. Плюс `newStr[0] = 'null';` это не присвоение `null` переменной `newStr[0]`. Это вообще не корректный код, т.к. в одинарные кавычки можно заключать только одиночные символы.

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1041882

Comment: Решение уже принято)
Код добавления в вопросе написан в методе connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В элементах массива не `'null'` (что это вообще такое?), а `null`.

Строка `"null"` - это то, как конвертируется `null`-ссылка в строку. Инициализируйте массив пустыми строками.

```
String[] newStr = new String[3];
java.util.Arrays.setAll(newStr, i -> ""); // or java.util.Arrays.fill(newStr, "");
```

или

```
String[] newStr = new String[] {"", "", ""};
```

Comment: 'null', потому, что при добавлении одного любого символа, например 'B', строка будет содержать уже 'nullB'.

Comment: @n199a Строка `"null"` - это то, как конвертируется `null`-ссылка в строку. Инициализируйте массив пустыми строками.

Comment: Если не инициализировать массив строк пустой строкой, то туда записывается null, так, уже понятно. Как инициализировать пустой строкой массив строк? В приведенном примере это уже не инициализация, это изменение строки после инициализации. Вопрос: как во время инициализации сделать пустую строку?

Comment: String[] newStr = new String[] {"", "", ""}; это не пойдет, потому что размер массива строк определяется в процессе работы программы и всегда разный

Comment: @n199a Тогда решение - `fill` или `setAll`.